# $locationprovider.html5mode turns off my css when I refresh page

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

All is good when I delete `$locationprovider.html5mode(true)`. But when the html5mode is on some troubles are happening:( SO the main error is that css styles doesnt work after I refresh the page.What can It be and what`s the way to fix?
I use AngularJS ui-router can it be the reason?

Comment: Always links the css using absolute path like /css/abc.css

Also add proper redirects in server side so that it serves home page even if it requests other url.

If using angular 2, angular-universal is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by funny way. The problem was `<base href="/"></base>` was placed AFTER links to css files. When I place `<base href="/"></base>` on the top of the HEAD all worked fine. Hope It will help someone.